# Java: cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I'm taking an intro Computer Science class at university and on our second assaignment I've been getting an error of "Cannot find symbol" when i try changing the stuudent3's name. If I take the statement out it will get up to 75% but then read the error "compile error: changeName method not called properly." Though maybe you guys could help me out and explain to me what is wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
student3 = student3.changeName(Bill);
```

(This is where I get the error, **Bill is underlined in red** and it stats that it cannot find the symbol.) 
I'm currently using netbeans if that changes anything.

```
import ProvidedClasses.Student; // Necessary! Do Not Remove!

public class Question1 
{
    /*  
1) Declare 3 Student object references (variables) with the identifiers student1, student2, and student3

2)
 Use the default constructor method of the Student class to instantiate an Student object and assign it to
            the student1 object reference (variable)

3) Use the alternate constructor method of the Student class to instantiate a Student object by passing the followin arguments:
            First, the String literal "Richard Rosby"
            Then, a non-negative integer literal of your choosing
            Assign that object to the object reference student2

4) Assign the object reference student3 the value of the object reference Student2

 5) Declare 2 String objects oldName and newName

 6) Assign oldName the value returned by a method call to the getName method for the student2 object

7) Call the changeName method on the student3 object and pass your own choice of a new name as an argument

8) Assign newName the value returned by a method call to the getName method for the student3 object
    */

    public static Object[] question1()
    {
        // Your Code Goes Here



       Student student1 = new Student();
       Student student2 = new Student("Richard Rosby", 23);
       Student student3 = student2;
               student3 = student3.changeName(Bill);
       String oldName = student2.getName();
       String newName = student3.getName();



        // Necessary for Unit Test. Do not remove or modify!
        return new Object[] {student1, student2, student3, oldName, newName};         
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean `"Bill"` instead of `Bill`?

Comment: While it's generally helpful to include as much context as possible, the details of the assignment are probably not relevant to the question!

Comment: When I put bill into double quotes i get an error of, "Incompatible types: Void can not be converted to Student." any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be `student3.changeName("Bill");` with the double quotes.

Without the double quotes, Java thinks you are using an object or class.

EDIT:
By taking into account the new error you get (Regarding Incompatible types), the problem seems like the method changeName is not returning any thing.

So simply remove `student3 =` from the statement `student3 = student3.changeName("Bill");`, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Student`'s constructor accepts a `java.lang.String`. Assuming you intended to use the literal `"Bill"`, you should surround it with quotes (`"`) - otherwise java interprets it as a variable name, which was of course never declared:

```
student3 = student3.changeName("Bill");
```

Comment: Okay so I did what you suggested and changed Bill to "Bill" but now it says "Incompatible types: Void cannot be converted to Student." any idea on how to fix this?